# Recursive function not returning Int

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I have a recursive function that will repeat the function until the if condition is not met then output an integer. However the function outside this function that requires an integer is receiving a unit. How should I modify the code in order to return an int?

```
count(r,c,1,0)

   def count(r: Int, c: Int, countR: Int, lalaCount: Int): Int = {
    if (countR < (r + 1)) count(r,c,countR + 1, lalaCount + countR)
    else (lalaCount + c + 1)
   }
```

This is the whole program

```
object hw1 {
  def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {

   count(r,c,1,0)

   def count(r: Int, c: Int, countR: Int, lalaCount: Int): Int = {
    if (countR < (r + 1)) count(r,c,countR + 1, lalaCount + countR)
    else (lalaCount + c + 1)
   }
  } //On this line eclipse is saying "Multiple markers at this line
    //- type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Int
    //- type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Int
pascal(3,4)
```

}

Comment: What makes you think it is receiving a `Unit`? Your function is defined as returning an `Int`, so you're definitely getting an `Int` back, how did you determine that you're getting `Unit` back?

Comment: I made an edit. Elipse is telling me that.

Comment: You should consider to accept some answers if they help to resolve your problems

Comment: Please do not violate the [*Honor code*](http://help.coursera.org/customer/portal/articles/601398-honor-code) principles you agreed. This is a homework assignment coming from [*Functional Programming Principles in Scala*](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-2012-001/class/index) online course.

Comment: I am not violating the honor code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value returned from `pascal` is the last expression it contains. You want it to be your evaluation of `count` but that's not the last thing. Assignments (def, val etc) are of type Unit, as you've discovered:

```
  def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {

   count(r,c,1,0) // => Int

   def count(r: Int, c: Int, countR: Int, lalaCount: Int): Int = {
    if (countR < (r + 1)) count(r,c,countR + 1, lalaCount + countR)
    else (lalaCount + c + 1)
   } // => Unit
  }
```

Just move `count(r,c,1,0)` *after* the `def` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: So pascal looks at count(r,c,1,0) first and says this is a unit instead of realizing that it calls a local function that returns an int?

Comment: Luigi was saying that the `def` inside the function actually gets evaluated and returns `Unit`. I've edited the answer to make that a little bit more clear.